# Firebase auth.id mapping to user specific route

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm stuck on the Firebase security rules. I don't understand how it maps the "url" into the `$variable`.

How are these two mapped?

```
"$user": {
  ".read": "$user == 42" // where does this $user get its value from?
}
```

Given this rule set:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$provider": {
          "$user": {
            ".read": "$user == auth.id",
            ".write": "$user == auth.id",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does not work:

```
Attempt to read /users/twitter/169508069 with auth={"id":169508069}
    /
    /users
    /users/twitter
    /users/twitter/169508069: "$user == auth.id"
        => false

No .read rule allowed the operation.
Read was denied.
```

Works: (changed rule to the fixed user id)

```
Attempt to read /users/twitter/169508069 with auth={"id":169508069}
    /
    /users
    /users/twitter
    /users/twitter/169508069: "169508069 == auth.id"
        => true

Read was allowed.
```

Based on the documentation of [$location variables](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/path.html), it looks to me like I have the mapping from `$user` to `".read": "$user == auth.id"` correct, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoah! So the actual problem is that I registered the rule for auth.id in the simulator as `169508069`, the integer. $user has the value of `"169508069"`, the string. When I manually set the value to compare against (an integer), of course it works.

Pretty tricky to track down.

Suggestion for the Firebase folks: print the computed value of the `$variable` in the security simulator output to help isolate security issues.

For others, just a heads up to be wary of data types.

Comment: You can also [create a login token](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/D4YL8/embedded/result/) with debug: true on the client to see output similar to the simulator's while on the client.